# Should I use the phrase "sufficient understanding" or "cultural capacity"?

Tags: vocabulary

> Many of us lack the **sufficient understanding** to support someone who takes the lead or innovates something...

Would you please suggest other words we could substitute for the bold part?

And, what is your impression of the phrase "cultural capacity"? Do you know any synonyms for it?

Comment: Would you explain in more detail the idea that you're trying to express? Most people find it difficult to support an innovator because they ____?

Comment: What @ColleenV said. There are lots of alternatives to **sufficient understanding** here, but we need to know *exactly what meaning OP intends*. All I would say is that ***cultural capacity*** is an extremely vague term (especially when applied to *individuals*, rather than an entire culture/nation/civilisation). Oh, and the first *"**the**"* is idiomatically incorrect here.

Comment: "vision". No idea about 'cultural capacity'. Do you mean the knowledge to understand a culture (that isn't your own)?

Comment: First thanks. I mean a series of understanding which we must or should have for doing somethings as followings: 1.for eating. 2. for how reacting to academia.et cetera,.

Comment: I think you will distinguish between these when you want to call these terms, such as:know-how and et cetera.

Comment: [lack sufficient understanding, no the]. You could just say: lack sufficient knowledge

Answer (score 1):

In place of *know-how*, you could employ the french equivalent, *saviour-faire*:

> Many of us lack the *saviour-faire* to support someone who takes the lead or innovates something...

The old fashioned (obsolete?) term *where with all* could also be used instead of **sufficient understanding**:

> Many of us lack the *where with all* to support someone who takes the lead or innovates something...

However, both of these choices make the sense of the sentence change somewhat, and if, as I believe, *cultural capacity* was an original option as a synonym, I feel that it would make the sentence as lot more plausible.

> Many of us lack the **cultural capacity** to support someone who takes the lead or innovates something...

Makes the subscribers to a particular culture sound as if they lack it within themselves, as a culture, to support a leader.

Where as

> Many of us lack the *sufficient understanding* to support someone who takes the lead or innovates something...

Makes everyone sound like that are unintelligent, per se, and are too ignorant to understand that they have to support a natural leader. This is a bit too much of a sweeping statement to make sense.

---

Note that, as [FumbleFingers suggests](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34820/should-i-use-the-phrase-sufficient-understanding-or-cultural-capacity/73041#comment-65405), the first *the* is unnecessary, so your original sentence should have read:

> Many of us lack **sufficient understanding** to support someone who takes the lead or innovates something...

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you want is "know-how". 
http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/know-how

If the innovation is of a technical nature, then most people in that field might not have the technical knowledge that sets the innovator apart from his peers. For example, a new surgical technique for transplanting bodily organs. "Know-how" fits that context well.

If the innovation is of an artistic nature, say cubist painting in the early days, then many  more conventional artists might not have the understanding to act as spokespersons for the new artistic movement.  Know-how fits that context less well.  Perhaps "insight" might be better.

But without a more specific question, who knows what the OP has in mind? "Support" is also a very vague term in addition to the others.

Comment: I really don't see how people down vote around here. It seems to me there are a lot of neophytes sniffing around. There is nothing wrong with your suggestion in view of the OP's lack of context....